# How to Sort rows based on Column matching data using python?

Tags: python, excel, sorting

I have table as below and i want to sort as expected output as below. How to perform using Python. Table is inside Excel/csv format. ?

[image]

I want to Match column1 data with Column2 data and want to add new 2 columns(5&6) with sorted data as below.

[image]

How to perform above operation using python ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the approach is as follows,

Create an empty dataframe and append the matched column values as per your logic

Merge the created dataframe with your original dataframe.

I have made an attempt using your example data and here goes it:

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.read_excel(<location_to_file>) # Reading excel in to pandas
dat = pd.DataFrame(dat) # Converting to a pandas dataframe
dat1 = pd.DataFrame([])
for n in range(dat.shape[0]):
    for m in range(dat.shape[0]):
        if dat['Col1'][n] == dat['Col2'][m]:
            dat1 = dat1.append(pd.DataFrame({'Column5': dat.iloc[m][2], 'Column6': dat.iloc[m][3]}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
# print(dat1)
df = pd.concat([dat, dat1], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Input(as dataframe):

```
  Col1 Col2     Col3  Col4
0  ABC  DEF       12  DGMN
1  PQR  MNO       17  DGSD
2  DEF  JPG   United  DGFS
3  JPG  PQR     21Hi  DFPR
4  SQL  STF      STM  DGBC
5  PQR  YZW  Hello90  DGSF
6  MNO  ABC      DQT  DGCV
7  STF  SQL     A18B  DGFD
```

Intermediate/Temp dataframe:

```
  Column5 Column6
0     DQT    DGCV
1    21Hi    DFPR
2      12    DGMN
3  United    DGFS
4    A18B    DGFD
5    21Hi    DFPR
6      17    DGSD
7     STM    DGBC
```

Output(df):

```
  Col1 Col2     Col3  Col4 Column5 Column6
0  ABC  DEF       12  DGMN     DQT    DGCV
1  PQR  MNO       17  DGSD    21Hi    DFPR
2  DEF  JPG   United  DGFS      12    DGMN
3  JPG  PQR     21Hi  DFPR  United    DGFS
4  SQL  STF      STM  DGBC    A18B    DGFD
5  PQR  YZW  Hello90  DGSF    21Hi    DFPR
6  MNO  ABC      DQT  DGCV      17    DGSD
7  STF  SQL     A18B  DGFD     STM    DGBC
```

While this snippet could be improved further for performance by vectorizing the operations. Hope this would help you get started.

**Note**
Please show your research efforts in addressing/solving the issue you're posting. That would motivate SO members to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your question is trying to do two things:

1. Read the data from excel into your python program.
2. Manipulate the data once it's in python.

For #1, you could use something like [Python's xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) or there are several other xls(x) parsers.

I would start with that and see if you can get the data into python. It would look something like this:

```
import xlrd

# open your workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('mybook.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# now go through the rows and do what you want with them
for x in range(sh.nrows):
    for y in range(sh.ncols):
        value = sh.cell(x,y).value
        # and do something with this value.
```

I hope the above gets you started on the above.

Comment: Hi Henry H, Thanks for Answer. But i already have code to read data. Just i want to Compare with second column and sort rows as shown in expected output.